# Error CS7069: Reference to type System.IO.FileInfo'

Tags: xamarin

I am building a portable library, however, I got this error:

> /Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/Phoenix.Client.Portable/Socket.cs(15,15):
>   Error CS7069: Reference to type `System.IO.FileInfo' claims it is
>   defined assembly`mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', but it could not be found (CS7069)
>   (Phoenix.Client.Portable)

At:

```
var dataString = data.ToString(Formatting.None);
Action callback = () =>
{
   //THIS WILL CAUSE THE ERROR ABOVE
   _conn.Send(dataString);
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referencing any other libraries in your PCL? If so and if they were built with a different version of the .NET framework, this can cause this error.

See a similar issue when someone tried to use the websocket-sharp library in their PCL project:
https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/100

From the above:
"That websocket-sharp library is built with .NET Framework 3.5 as target framework. And if the Portable Class Library supports only .NET Framework 4.0 or higher, i guess you cannot use it in your Portable Class Library project."

Comment: Thanks, I've already fixed it, I have recompiled the library removing methods that has incompatible signatures with PCL which U discovered that I don't need :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another monodevelop bug that causes `.csproj` files to be made without `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` or lose it somehow.
It **won't** be added back if you change the framework version from the project properties window. You have to add one manually.
sample:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>  

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```